# Why can't I pass an object of type T to a method on an object of type <? extends T>?

Tags: java, generics

In Java, assume I have the following class Container that contains a list of class Items:

```
    public class Container<T>
    {
        private List<Item<? extends T>> items;

        private T value;

        public Container(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void addItem(Item<? extends T> item)
        {
            items.add(item);
        }

        public void doActions()
        {
            for (Item<? extends T> item : items)
            {
                item.doAction(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class Item<T>
    {
        public abstract void doAction(T item);
    }
```

Eclipse gives the error:
`The method doAction(capture#1-of ? extends T) in the type Item is not applicable for the arguments (T)`

I've been reading generics examples and various postings around, but I still can't figure out why this isn't allowed.  Eclipse also doesn't give any helpful tips in its proposed fix, either.  The variable `value` is of type T, why wouldn't it be applicable for `? extends T`?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the following program

```
public class Cell<T> { 
  private T value;

  public void set(T t) { value = t; }
  public T get() { return value; }
}


Cell<Integer> ci = new Cell<Integer>();
Cell<? extends Number> cn = ci;

cn.set(new Double(5.0));  // (A) <-- Compile error here


Integer n = ci.get(); // (B) Runtime error!
```

As you said, the (A) line does not compile. If this line were legal then, at runtime, the program will pass a `Double` object to the `cn.set()` call where `cn`'s dynamic type is `Cell<Integer>`.

When execution subsequently arrives at (B), `ci.get()` will return a `Double` object---the one that was passed in (A)---were the declaration of `ci` says that its `get()` method is guaranteed to return an `Integer`. In order to prevent this conundrum (which actually breaks the JVM's strong typing philosophy), the compiler disallows assignment from `T` to `<? extends T>`.

Comment: This makes sense.  I hadn't considered such an intermediary assignment.

Answer (score 2):

> PECS - Producer-extends, consumer-super

replace all occurrences of `extends` with `super` in your declarations (including the one you omitted, in the loop), and it compiles :)

Comment: I actually tried that, but it doesn't get me quite what I wanted.  However, it may be the best I can hope for.

Comment: I actually wanted to be able to add an Item<S> to the Container where S is a subclass of T.  With super I can add, for example, an Item<Object>.

Answer (score 1):

See [my (only!) blog post](http://blog.codeaholics.org/2011/generics-and-the-mystical-wildcard/). It doesn't directly talk about the "? extends T" case, but everywhere you see "?", just imagine it says "? extends Object" and it should become clear.

Basically, you've got a list of "something that extends T", but you don't know what that something is at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The bounding is reversed. Item<X> can take an X or a subclass of X for its doAction. Now `? extends T` means that X is a subclass of T. So you're passing in a T into an item that expects an X, which is a subclass of T, not the other way around.